# How to save space in a Trie composed of words?

Tags: c#, algorithm, asp.net-core, data-structures, trie

I have a giant Trie which I have created using C#  (Hashtables).
I have an excel sheet with 1 million rows and roughly 10-15 columns,

**Each cell has a value  as shown below:**

[image: Dictionary]

**Instead of storing characters as value, I am storing it as follows:**

[image]

Now the problem is after loading it into the memory this occupies roughly 3-4GBs.

It could be the overhead of creating so many dictionaries. The performance is awesome. But the space it occupies is pretty expensive. Is there a way to optimize it?

I will be having a collection of roughly 5000 lineitem rows which I will have to validate against these 1million rows that had been inserted. The row has to match in its entirety.

Is there a way I could optimize this for space?

**One important piece of information:** * means that the lineitem could have ANY value for that property. Had that not been the case I could have just concatenated each cell of a row and stored it in a dictionary.

Then concatenated lineitem and looked up in the dictionary. Since * means any value. It won't work.

The data itself is not that huge. It's roughly 200-300Mb when serialized and written to a textile. I guess it's the gazillion dictionaries that is causing the bloat.

Following is the code. Please note that Dictionary is of string,int because I am converting each unique word to an integer so that it reduces some space. For eg if "ABC" appears 10 times in excel then it will be assigned "1" for all the instances of "ABC" but "XYZ" will be assigned 2 and so on.

**Code:**

```
var trie = Serializer.Deserialize<SuffixTrie>(System.IO.File.OpenRead(@".\Serialized\trieproto.txt")); //trieproto file is roughly 100MB for 1M rows in excel.


namespace Trie
{
   

    [ProtoContract]
    public class TrieNode
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public Dictionary<int, TrieNode> Children { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, TrieNode>();
    }
     [ProtoContract]
    public class SuffixTrie
    {
        
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public TrieNode root { get; set; } = new TrieNode();
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public int endSymbol { get; set; } = -1;
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public int Count { get; set; } = 0;

        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public Dictionary<string, int> dictionary { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        public SuffixTrie()
        {

        }
        public SuffixTrie(DataTable ruleDt,Dictionary<string,int> dict)
        {
            this.dictionary = dict;
            PopulateSuffixTrieFrom(ruleDt);
        }

        public void PopulateSuffixTrieFrom(DataTable ruleDt)
        {


            for (int i = 0; i < ruleDt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(i);
                insertSubstringStartingAt(0, i, ruleDt);
                 
            }
        }
        public void insertSubstringStartingAt(int j, int i, DataTable ruleDt)
        {
            //ruleDt.Rows[i][j].ToString()

            TrieNode node = root;
            for (int idx = j; idx < ruleDt.Columns.Count; idx++)
            {
                // if (ruleDt.Rows[i][j].ToString() == "*") continue;

                var cell = Convert.ToInt32(ruleDt.Rows[i][idx].ToString());
                
                if (!node.Children.ContainsKey(cell))
                {
                    node.Children.Add(cell, new TrieNode());
                }
                node = node.Children[cell];
            }

            node.Children[endSymbol] = null;
            Count++;
        }


        public bool Contains(DataTable lineitemsDt, int i)
        {
           //not adding this to avoid making post too long
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems odd that it would take up that much space.  With some rough napkin math, if your average node size is 4 characters and each character is roughly 4 bytes, with 1 million rows and 15 columns, that is still only 240-250 million bytes, or a few hundred megs. It seems like something is fundamentally wrong with how your Trie is allocating.

Comment: @DavidL I am confused too. After serializing it to a file its roughly 200-300 MBs. I have a very simple app for poc and I thought may be reading the excel in creating a lot of objects. So I seriazed the trie and then loaded the Trie object from that serialized file. It's still 4GB. I could Add code if that would help.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect the downvote is because there isn't any code or any way for anyone to reproduce your behavior.  Adding code would be massively helpful.

Comment: @DavidL I have added the code.  I could add more if needed.

Answer (score 0):

> One important piece of information: * means that the lineitem could have ANY value for that property. Had that not been the case I could have just concatenated each cell of a row and stored it in a dictionary.
>
> Then concatenated lineitem and looked up in the dictionary. Since * means any value. It won't work.

If those columns are always wildcards, then you could simply substitute those values with asterisks when you concatenate `lineitem`. Then the dictionary lookup would work.

Comment: I wish I could do that. Wildcard * means that in the lineitem that property could have just about anything. So if ColB has * then in lineitem, ColB could be "ABCD","X","ANYTHING"

Comment: So then replace `ColB`'s value with an asterisk when concatenating `lineitem` for the dictionary lookup: `var lineitemStr = $"{lineitem.ColA}*{lineitem.ColC}{lineitem.ColD}";`.

Comment: The position of * is not fixed. Its not line ColB is always going to be *. In the excelsheet that has 1M rows (lets call them rules) you could have * in ColB for first row then for second row you could have a value for ColB

Comment: If asterisks can appear in any column, then shortcuts like this won't work and any "fast" solution will approach the functionality of a database engine. So maybe you should just use a lightweight database like SQLite?

Comment: I tried it with SQL server. Created indexes on all the columns. It took over 4 minutes to produce result. WIth Trie I am able to get result in milliseconds.

Comment: I'm no SQL server expert, but 4 minutes sounds way too long. Were all the columns typed as text (`varchar`)? Or were they typed as `int` etc. with `NULL` representing wildcards? I could see that potentially making a huge difference in performance.

Comment: they are all string fields so they were varchar. Also, I am validating 5000 lineitems against  1M rules.

Comment: I hope you did a single database query and not 5,000 separate ones. (That would definitely explain the 4 minutes.)

Comment: I tried both. Multiple quries and a single query with join.